# Can I pass data to the Codeigniter output class without displaying it?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, dompdf

I'm working on a way for users to be able to generate PDF copies of invoices and other tabular data. To do this, I've wrapped [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) into a library that I can use with CI and created a method that will generate a PDF based on the return value of CI's `output->get_output()`. The wrapper is similar to [this one on Github](https://github.com/hadiariawan/CodeIgniter-Dompdf-Library).

The problem is, I can't figure out a way to get the view (and HTML/CSS needed for the PDF) into CI's output class other than `load->view()`, which is going to write to the browser.

My only other choice would be to use curl to request the page, but that seems so silly to do since I can get it right from the output buffer. I just don't want the HTML sent to the browser, since I set headers telling the browser to expect a PDF.

To be clear, this is what I want to accomplish (in the order that I want to accomplish it):

1. Do everything I'd normally do to prepare the view for display
2. Load the view into the CI output class, but not display it
3. Pass the return value of `output->get_output()` to my dompdf library
4. Set the appropriate headers
5. Execute my dompdf method that will send the PDF to the browser

I don't see any way of doing step 2 based on the [output class documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html).

Is it possible to get a view into the output class without displaying it? If so, how? I'm using CI 2.0.3.

**Edit**

The very helpful [Anthony Sterling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734499/anthony-sterling) pointed out that [I can just get what I want from the loader class](https://twitter.com/AnthonySterling/status/241426835634786304) by setting the third argument telling it to return a string rather than render the view to TRUE. E.g.:

```
$lotsaHtml = $this->load->view('fooview', $somearray, TRUE);
```

And that would be better in my particular instance since I don't need to load partials. However, this is still a valid and (I think) interesting question, it would also be handy to know if I could get the same from the OB, perhaps if I *did* have a bunch of partials. Those could be concatenated, but yuck.

It seems like I should be able to get the output class to not render anything (else, why does `get_output()` exist?) so I can do something else with everything it knows about. I just can't find a way to make that happen.

**Edit 2**

Some pseudo (but not far from reality) code illustrating what I hope to do, by showing what I did and then explaining what I actually *wanted* to do.

Let's say I have a public method `genpdf($id)` in a controller named `invoice` using a model named `inv`:

```
public function genpdf($invoiceId) {
    $this->load->library('dompdflib');
    $this->pagedata['invoice_data'] = $this->inv->getInvoice($invoiceId);
    $html = $this->load->view('pdfgen', $this->pagedata, TRUE);
    $this->dompdflib->sendPdf($html);
}
```

That is almost identical to code that I have that works right now. There, I ask the loader to parse and give me the results of the `pdfgen` view as a string, which I pass to the function in my dompdf wrapper that sets headers and sends the PDF to the browser.

It just seemed like this would be easy to do by just getting the output buffer itself (after setting headers correctly / etc).

Or do I just have to call the output class `append_output()` in succession with every partial I load?

Multiple methods loading a plethora of models need to work together to generate these (they're going in as an afterthought), so I was hoping to just collect it all and retrieve it directly from the output class. It could be that I just have to talk gradually to `output->append_output()` to make that happen.

Comment: if the pages are cached, maybe you can get it from there?

Comment: @Jurgo Unfortunately no, the pages themselves can't be cached (well, perhaps they could, but for an _extremely_ short amount of time which wouldn't work reliably).

Comment: I can't figure out what's up with this. Somehow the output class `_display` gets called at the end of a controller method automatically (I think). If you `exit` as the last step in your controller method, the function won't get called and you can `echo $this->output->get_output()` as expected, handling the output "manually" without any leakage. However, no headers that you set with the output class will be sent either (and things like the profiler won't run), so it's not a solution just a clue.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yes, I call `_display()` directly in a few places in my AJAX controllers, it lets me make methods like `displaySuccess()` or `displayError()` that flush the OB and die (extremely handy to avoid a nest of if / else / elseifs and error outin the constructor if the request is not AJAX). But I can't seem to find a way to pack more in the buffer without loading a view.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by all that, I rarely use the output class directly but I am interested in this - if you have some sample problem code related to the issue that would be motivational.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Sorry, too much or too little coffee over here, not sure which :) What I meant was, I frequently use `_display()` to forcibly flush the OB prior to deliberately exiting, but I think the only 'good' way for me to do what I describe in the question is to extend the output class. Not 100% sure, still going through it, but that's what I'm suspecting.

Comment: Actually, the output class _does_ have an `append_output()` function, allowing you to tack on what you'd like to the output string. Still, `$this->output->append_output()` would be the technically correct answer to this question, which I'll add later (hoping to include some code that addresses this specific set of needs too)

Comment: That's what I was testing with, both `set_output` and `append_output`, and mixing in a straight `echo`, and I couldn't seem to get it to work the way I expected even though both of those functions are totally generic (they just set/append the `final_output` property, no nonsense). If you could show a bit of code that demonstrates the problem and what you hope to accomplish that would be really helpful.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Edited, added an example of what I ended up doing because I could not figure out how to just get it into the output class.

Comment: @TimPost you could utilize `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`. It ain't pretty, but if you need to get it done now, you will do just fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

...so - do I understand correctly - you want to get the whole final output (not just the view) as a string AND not display it to the user? Why dont you just overload the controllers _output() function?

```
class Your_controller extends CI_Controller
{
       function stuff()
       {
           // do whatever - prep $data etc
           $this->load->view('your_view', $data);
       }

       function _output($output)
       {
           // send $output to your library - get results blah blah
           $result_pdf_file = $this->your_pdf_library_generator($output);

           // Show something else to the user
           echo "hi - I'm not what you expected - but here is your PDF";

           echo $result_pdf_file; // or something like that
       }
 }
```

This means you can send ANYTHING you like to the output class - but nothing is displayed except what you want.

There are ways to improve this idea (i.e. hooks, variables to turn output on/off etc) - but the simplest would be to have this controller specifically for your pdf_generation command.

> I don't see any way of doing step 2 based on the output class documentation. Is it possible to get a view into the output class without displaying it? If so, how? I'm using CI 2.0.3.

The controller _output() documentation is actually in the [CI controller documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#output), which is why it eluded you.

Comment: That is _precisely_ what I was looking for. Had I noticed it first, I would not have been going down the rabbit hole of trying to extend the output class itself. I can see why they put it where they did, but some breadcrumbs leading to it in the output controller docs would have saved some time :)

Comment: yeah - i only knew of it from another project. BTW - is your dompdf library wrapper something you might be interested in sharing? I'm literally about to use it in one of my CI projects. If so, my email is in my bio - if not - thats cool I understand - thought'd I just ask and try my luck ;)

Comment: I gave a link to the one that inspired the one that I wrote. It's on Github. Can I share the actual wrapper? No, it's not an open project, but I spent literally ten minutes writing one so you have the same start I did. Also, I put a bounty on this which is going your way tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the link - thats perfect. And thanks for the bounty - I appreciate it :)

Comment: Quite welcome. I'll award it as soon as it lets me (not even moderators are immune to the mandatory wait for awarding a bounty).